# Unable to open port in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mysql

I have a small VPS with 15GB disk space and 1 GB of RAM, and i decide to install LEMP stack, SSL certificate, and WordPress.
When i install WordPress, i have "Error establishing database connection". Checking with MySQL connect script, i have "Access Denied" error.
I already try solutions on internet. Check DB name, DB hostname, username, and password, altering user, granting permission, still nothing.
Then i asked my friend. He says port 3306 (port for MySQL) is closed. *maybe that's why my scripts unable to contact MySQL.*
I checked with `ufw`, I already allow port 3306. But on `nmap`, that port is still closed.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post the output of `netstat -tulpn`?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/tfok4mC.png

Comment: Now please also show that connection script (including all variables like DB hostname) so we know how you try to connect to the DB, please.